# Why MessageBox.Show() need to be in code to update label and textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string text, st;
    int i;
    string k;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        try
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Test\Readfile.txt");
            text = sr.ReadToEnd();

            string textData = Regex.Replace(text, @"[^0-9a-zA-Z]+", " ");

            char[] whitespace = new char[] { ' ', '\t' };
            string[] data = textData.Split(whitespace);
            int i = 1;

            while (i < data.Length)
            {
                st = data[i];

                string[] source = text.Split(new char[] { '.', '?', '!', ' ', ';', ':', ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                var matchQuery = from word in source
                                 where word.ToLowerInvariant() == st.ToLowerInvariant()
                                 select word;

                int wordCount = matchQuery.Count();
                k += wordCount + ": " + st + Environment.NewLine;
                textBox1.Text = k;
                //MessageBox.Show(k);
                label1.Text = "wrote " + i + " rows";
                //MessageBox.Show(k);
                i++;
            }
            try
            {
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Test\WhatFound.txt", k.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception ce)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ce.Message);
            }
            //StreamWriter sr4 = new StreamWriter(@"C:\WhatFound.txt");
            //sr4.Write(k);

        }
        catch (Exception ce)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

The `label1` and `textBox1` texts are shown only if there is a `MessageBox.Show()` otherwise the label and the textbox doesn't update.

How do I fix it?

Comment: You write something to textbox1 and without waiting it to be displayed, write some other text. Computers are fast....... (BTW: Don't use Thread.Sleep as suggested in one answer...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are updating them in a loop without giving the OS time to refresh the view. I think you should try to use an [Application.DoEvents(](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents(v=vs.110).aspx)) inside your loop. This way you will give the operating system some time to process the paint messages and update the form.

```
while (i < data.Length)
{
    st = data[i];

    string[] source = text.Split(new char[] { '.', '?', '!', ' ', ';', ':', ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    var matchQuery = from word in source
                    where word.ToLowerInvariant() == st.ToLowerInvariant()
                    select word;

    int wordCount = matchQuery.Count();
    k += wordCount + ": " + st + Environment.NewLine;
    textBox1.Text = k;
    label1.Text = "wrote " + i + " rows";
    Application.DoEvents();
    i++;
}
```

Comment: For future readers: [Is DoEvents Evil?](http://blog.codinghorror.com/is-doevents-evil/)

Answer (score 2):

Place a call to `DoEvents` at the end of your loop:

```
Application.DoEvents();
i++;
```

Comment: For future readers: [Is DoEvents Evil?](http://blog.codinghorror.com/is-doevents-evil/)

Answer (score 2):

You are updating the UI very fast. MessageBox gives your code a chance to update the UI.

If your intension is to slow down the update process, you can use [async/await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443(v=vs.110).aspx).

First change your method as:

```
async private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

then put

```
await Task.Delay(msec);
```

to some places (for ex, after setting text to the `label1`) in your code, to *wait* without blocking the UI thread.